# Until when is .NET Compact Framework 1.0 supported?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I'm wondering what is the date when Microsoft will stop supporting .NET CF 1.0. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) .NET CF SP3  was released at January 2005, so [standard 5 years support](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy) should end at January 2010.

However, I was unable to find a .NET Compact Framework on the [dev tools support lifetime list](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifeselectdevtools), so it's only a guess.

Do you know what is the official end of support date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tool that supports it is Studio 2003, so I'd guess that support for CF 1.0 would mirror the support for that tool.

Comment: According to http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=3040 the Mainstream Support for VS.NET 2003 ends at 10/14/2008 and Extended Support ends at 10/8/2013.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just treated as part of the .NET Framework 1.0, for which the [support expired in 2007, and extended support expired last July](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&p1=1248&x=10&y=9).  (For US.)

Comment: I don't think it's correct, because .NET CF 1.0 was released with VS.NET 2003 and .NET 1.1, not with .NET 1.0,